# SentenceTransformer model not load

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying the following code:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util

model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
```

and get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Expected one of cpu, cuda, mkldnn, opengl, opencl, ideep, hip, msnpu, xla 
device type at start of device string: meta
```

I have tried:

1. Downgrading transformers library to 4.6.0
2. Modify to:

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2', device=device)
```

Comment: Have you correctly installed pytorch with CUDA?

Comment: can you try changing device assignment to "device=torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')". which pytorch version are you using.

Comment: still not working. Im using torch==1.7.1